# Where can i find the local.properties file in Mac?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am implementing DeltaDna Smart Ads in Unity-Mac for Android Platform.
https://github.com/deltaDNA/unity-sdk

To implement SmartAds we need to open command line and run python download.py. This will download and copy the dependent AARs and Jar files into the Assets\DeltaDNAAds\Plugins\Android folder. Unity will pick these up when you build the APK.

But i get this error.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Where can i find this local.properties file?﻿

Answer (score 2):

Android studio creates it for you.

They look like this and sit in the root of the Android project.

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Mon May 09 15:14:03 BST 2016
sdk.dir=/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk
```

As you are building through unity my guess is you don't need to worry about it and just need to set the android sdk location in "Unity/Preferences" --> External Tools

Alternatively set ANDROID_HOME via bash as a pre build step

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk export         
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello Stuart,
I did try this before posting my question here.
I did changes in this script but It is automatically generated.
I changed it but still i got the same error in terminal.
Thanks for taking efforts.

Comment: If you are building with bash here are two lines to set up ANDROID_HOME for that session.

export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.3.4
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

(Update with correct location of the SDK that location is from installing the Android SDK with brew)

Thanks